# rudin's principles of mathematical analysis 10.31

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm working on rudin's principles of mathematical analysis(3rd edition).
There is problem too complex for me to solve.Please help me.
The problem is on p270-271 of text.

"Let T be 1-1 mapping of $Q^n$ into $R^n$, of class $\mathscr{C}$ '', whose Jacobian is positive ( at least in the interior of $Q^n$). Let E=$T(Q^n)$. By the inverse function theorem, E is the closure of an open subset of $R^n$. We define the positively oriented boundary of the set E to be the (n-1)-chain 
$\partial$T = $\partial\sigma_o$

If E=$T_1(Q^n)$=$T_2(Q^n)$, and if both $T_1$ and $T_2$ have positive Jacobians, is it true that $\partial$$T_1$ = $\partial$$T_2$? " "The answer is yes, but we shall omit the proof"

I tried to prove this particular statement, but I could not.
Please can anyone help me with this issue???

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for notation. This will greatly improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the inverse function theorem applied to the diffeomorphism $f=T_2^{-1}\circ T_1$. Because local diffeomorphisms are open maps, $f$ maps $\partial Q^n$ into $\partial Q^n$, as does $f^{-1}$.